# Magento2 Under which conditions magento order can be cancelled

Tags: magento2, cancel-orders

Magento2 I would like to know under which conditions an order can be cancelled or other vice under which conditions order can't be cancelled?

I am facing a strange issue where my orders are not getting cancelled.

I am not clear on which conditions should I check first to debug why my orders not getting cancelled Manually from admin or via script.

Can some once guide me on this? It will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this link can help you:

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/order-status-workflow-magento-2.html

and this

[Magento 2 order flow sequence](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174320/magento-2-order-flow-sequence)

Cheers